# Unable to get values from Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataset:

```
site_key                         site_det                             site_xls
169       [{'id': 'XYTTR_23412', 'det': '49', 'person': 'Aron'}]      AMB_129
124       [{'id': 'XYTTR_23699', 'det': '42', 'person': 'Mike'}]      AMB_239
149       [{'id': 'XYTTR_26455', 'det': '47', 'person': 'Ross'}]      AMB_126
```

I want only these values in my final dataset:

```
site_key        site_det     site_xls
169             23412        129
124             23699        239
149             26455        126
```

I tried with regex but it didn't worked... How can I get this values in my dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'site_key': {0: 169, 1: 124, 2: 149}, 
        'site_det': {0: [{'id': 'XYTTR_23412', 'det': '49', 'person': 'Aron'}], 
                     1: [{'id': 'XYTTR_23699', 'det': '42', 'person': 'Mike'}], 
                     2: [{'id': 'XYTTR_26455', 'det': '47', 'person': 'Ross'}]}, 
        'site_xls': {0: 'AMB_129', 1: 'AMB_239', 2: 'AMB_126'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['site_det'] = df.site_det.explode().apply(pd.Series)['id']\
    .str.extract(r'(\d+$)').astype(int)
df['site_xls'] = df.site_xls.str.extract(r'(\d+$)').astype(int)

print(df)

   site_key  site_det  site_xls
0       169     23412       129
1       124     23699       239
2       149     26455       126
```

*Explanation*:

- [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) will "[t]ransform each element of a list-like to a row, replicating index values". I.e. it will get rid of the list surrounding the `dicts` in this case.
- `.apply(pd.Series)` will next turn the dicts into a `df` with the keys as columns. From this `df` we only need col `id`.
- Next, we can use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract only the last part of the string. `r'(\d+$)'` meaning: capture all (one or more) digits (`\d+`) at the end (`$`) of a string.
- For your other col (`site_xls`) we need only the last step.

For an alternative to the last step, see the [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73753696/18470692) by @dnyll. However, if your strings can contain `'_'` multiple times, you'd want to use `.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True).iloc[:,-1]`.

Finally, if you run into the error: `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`, this will mean that one of your strings does not in fact end with one or more digits. The error in this case would result from trying to apply `astype(int)`. To be on the safe side, you could change it to `astype(float)`.

Answer (score 2):

Without *regex*:

```
df['site_det'] = df.site_det.explode().apply(pd.Series)['id'].str.split('_', expand=True)[1]
df['site_xls'] = df['site_xls'].str.split('_', expand=True)[1]
```

Output:

```
   site_key site_det site_xls
0       169    23412      129
1       124    23699      239
2       149    26455      126
```